# cordova and html to enforce numpad in mobile even if the input type="text"

Tags: html, mobile, cordova

I know I can use type="number" to display the number pad but the issue is that I want to reformat the input according to the entered number to a string.

So I want to have a text field but it should display number pad on tap. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically change the type of the field. Something like:

```
onFocus = "this.type = 'number'";

onBlur = "this.type = 'text'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say stick with the type="text" and then do a `parseInt()` on the input val.